# Unknown Startup Disk

Tags: macbook-pro

[image: bugged windows startup disk]

My problem is that I don't have any Windows install on my MacBook yet but for some reason the Windows Startup Disk keeps showing up when I hold down option key for startup. As far as I know, I have tried everything to remove it but it's not working, I tried look in Startup Disk under System Preferences but the only thing I see is the Mac OS, I even tried installing Windows then removed it but the bugged Windows is still there I really don't know what else to do.

Answer (score 1):

[This post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/122192/remove-windows-entry-from-mac-boot-loader) seems to have a solution. It's probable that there's still an entry in the EFI for Windows even though the partition isn't there any more.