# Delete Bootcamp Partition and recover Disk Full Space

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, disk-format, space

I have a problem with my Bootcamp partition. I decided to delete it because I don't use Windows anymore. I went through Bootcamp Assistant, tried to uninstall Windows but didn't work that way.

So I formated with Disk Utility my 40 GB Bootcamp Partition and it's now empty.

Now, I struggle in reuniting the 2 partitions and have my full 128 GB space back.
--> I tried to follow this tutorial but in vain :

[I deleted my Bootcamp partition but can't resize my OS X partition](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/145292/i-deleted-my-bootcamp-partition-but-cant-resize-my-os-x-partition)

I unmounted both volumes and I'm stuck at the 2nd step of the tutorial :

```
gpt add -b <disk0s4 start position> -t windows /dev/disk0
```

**It says " No space available".**
Does anyone know what's going on here?

---

The output of `sudo gpt -r show disk0`:

```
    start       size  index  contents
        0          1         PMBR
        1          1         Pri GPT header
        2         32         Pri GPT table
       34          6         
       40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
   409640  147408336      2  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
147817976    1269536      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
149087512        744         
149088256   87627736      4  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
236715992     262151         
236978143         32         Sec GPT table
236978175          1         Sec GPT header
```

Comment: Hi klano thanks for the answer. 
Sorry I'm beginner in this, when should I type your command?

Thanks

Comment: Ok I add the information on a separate answer

Answer (score 1):

The linked method to create a fake Boot Camp partition doesn't work because the former partition is no empty space but an HFS volume (disk0s4). The `gpt` command won't add partitions in allocated disk space.

To resize your main partition (disk0s2) to the full ~120 GB, boot to your main macOS volume, delete the second HFS+ volume and expand your main partition:

```
diskutil eraseVolume Free Space disk0s4
```

Try to expand the main volume:

```
diskutil resizeVolume disk0s2 R
```

If the `R` size option fails try to use a real size like 120g or the percentage 100% (on some external disks this may fail because of some 2 TiB limit).

```
diskutil resizeVolume disk0s2 120473m
```

or more exactly:

```
diskutil resizeVolume disk0s2 120473067520b
```

or

```
diskutil resizeVolume disk0s2 100%
```

Comment: DAMN IT WORKED THANKS A LOT !

Actually the full size of the disk is 121.33 GB.

diskutil resizeVolume disk0s2 100% didn't work ( MediaKit reports partition (map) too small) 

nor diskutil resizeVolume disk0s2 121g  ( MediaKit reports not enough space on device ) 

But with 120g it worked fine.

Thanks again klanomath, so quick and efficient!

Comment: @ShqKa Full size means *full available size* here: 121.33 GB - EFI - Recovery HD - 2*40*512 Byte (partition tables + unallocated disk space to align to 4k blocks)